# How to search the database so that it does not show certain things (I do not know how to write it)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

Discord.js 13.6.0 | Node.js 16.14.2 | Mongoose 6.2.3

I want to do so that my bot searches the database to see if the guild should be removed or added

Example

I have 524 documents and 523 guilds

I want to check which document should be deleted

```
 const guilds = await this.client.guildsData.find() // This is my database
 const guilds2 = await this.client.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild.id); (This is all my bot guilds)

 const lb = await guilds
    .filter((r) => r.id !== `${guilds2}`)
    .sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id).map((r) => r)
    .map((r, i) => `${r.id}`)

 const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(`${lb.join(", ")}`)

 message.reply({ embeds: [embed] })
```

Anyone can help with it?

Btw this work

```
 const guilds = await this.client.guildsData.find() // This is my database

 const lb = await guilds
    .filter((r) => r.id !== "784242201344737292" && r.id !== "743513755060797501" && r.id !== "another ID")
    .sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id).map((r) => r)
    .map((r, i) => `${r.id}`)

 const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(`${lb.join(", ")}`)

 message.reply({ embeds: [embed] })
```

But I don't want to add or remove ID's all the time + I have a lot of servers and it would take a while before I add all of them

Sorry for my eng and explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `.find()` with an object to filter the results for you.

See https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

If you're just looking for a guild with one specific ID, then try `.findOne({id: guild_id_youre_looking_for})`

To go even further, if your sole goal is just to delete the document, then just use `.deleteOne({id: guid_id_here})`

Hope this helps!

Comment: How do I get an ID if my bot fails to register that some guild kick the bot?

Comment: `Discord.Client#on("guildDelete")` should detect your bot leaving guilds. If it isn't, then your bot might be offline when the server is removed, or your client's startup configuration is set up to cache less servers, meaning the event doesn't fire.

See https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildDelete

Comment: I have event guildDelete and guildCreate *facepalm*
Every now and then I have to restart the bot, sometimes during the restart some guild will add or kick the bot, so I did not receive a message that some guild add/kick bot
I want a command that will show me what guild I need to add to the database or remove from database